# Image is not getting displaced in the browser

Tags: javascript, html

I was doing an exercise on positioning the image, from a book. It says, using DOM, i.e. position, top and left value of the image we can move the image along the browser window using JavaScript.

The thing is i have the image getting displayed but when i enter the coordinates it doesn't get displaced to its new value. Please if someone could tell me where i am going wrong ??

here is the HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="newjavascript.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form action="">
          <p>
              Xcordinate : <input type="text" id="xCod" /><br/>
              Ycordinate : <input type="text" id="yCOd" /><br/>
          </p>
          <br/>
          <input type="submit" value="Set the Coordinates" onclick = "moveIt('image', document.getElementById('xCod').value,
              document.getElementById('yCod').value )" />
      </form>
      <div id="image" style="position: absolute; left:0; top:200px" >
          <img src="testing.jpg" alt="Picture Cannot be displayed" />
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the JavaScript file

```
function moveIt (movee, newTop, newLeft){
    dom = document.getElementById(movee).style;

    dom.top=newTop+"px";
    dom.left=newLeft+"px";

}
```

I have default browser for Google Chrome

Comment: Looks okay at first glance. Press `Ctrl + Shift + J` and click "Console" to see JavaScript errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's a `type="submit"` button, it is posting back and you're seeing the same page over again, you need to `return false;` to prevent the submit, like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Set the Coordinates" onclick = "moveIt('image', document.getElementById('xCod').value,
          document.getElementById('yCod').value); return false;" />
```

Also noticed in setting up the demo that your element IDs are off, this:

```
Ycordinate : <input type="text" id="yCOd" /><br/>
```

Should be:

```
Ycordinate : <input type="text" id="yCod" /><br/>
```

[You can test it out (with both of the above fixes) here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/86rFg/).

Answer (score 1):

You have a capitalization issue (or a typo in your post).  You have an element in your page with an id of `yCOd`, but your code is looking for an ID of `yCod`